# Mark occurance of word in a txt-file

Tags: python

i'm new both to this forum and to Python and I have problem with one of my programs, more specifically I could use some help to get started with my program. What I want my program to do is to see how often a word occur in a text, and if a word occur more than one time within the next 30 words I want to mark that word. An example:

Hello my name is Mark and *Hello* I like *Mark*

I have managed to open, change to lower case, split things like "," and "\n", read and print the text file, but I have problems to proceed from here. Should I use a Function in a Class or is there any other way? Some help with the coding would be much appreciated, Thank you in advance.

```
def open_file(file2, mode):
"""Checks if file exists, if it does, it opens and reads the textfile."""
try:
    file = open(file2, "r")
    file1 = file.read().lower().replace('.','').replace('\n', '')
    print(file1)
except(IOError) as e:
    print("Could not find the file", file2, "\n")

else:
    split = file1.split(" ")
    return split
```

Main
Filename = input("Enter the name of the file: ")+".txt"

```
open_file(Filename, "r")
```

Comment: I went ahead and escaped the asterisks on `Hello` and `Mark` so that they aren't interpreted as formatting marks. Is this an accurate representation of what you want?

Comment: Please supply the code you've written so far.

Comment: I added the code I have so far, as I said I haven't come so far, could se some tips regarding the counting mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You should split the lines to extract words (e.g. split(" ")), then put the words in a dictionary

Use the words as keys and place a counter as value, counting the number of occurences:

```
dict = {}
...
if my_word in dict:
  dict[my_word] += 1
else:
  dict[my_word] = 1
```

Then you will have to highlight the words whose count in the dictionnary are high (you can add <i> before and </i> after, that will put them in italics if you read the file as html.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but I am very new to python. What do you mean by "you can add <i> before and </i> after" ?

Comment: If you want to highlight the words, you can create an output file: output_file = open("output.html", "w") then you write your words in it: if dict[my_word] > 5: output.write("<i>%s</i>" % my_word) else: output.write(my_word)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have read the file and tokenized it (removed punctuation and breaking it into words) and have normalized the words (all in lower-case and maybe removed diacritics). Let's say these tokens are contained in a list called `tokens`.

Now to identify if the same token has appeared already within the last 30 tokens, you can use a sliding window.

```
window = []
for token in tokens:
    if token in window:
        print('repeated token {}'.format(token))
        #process accordingly
    window.append(token)
    window = window[-30:] #trim to last 30 entries
```

Let's further say you want to put `^` around repeated words:

```
window = []
for token in tokens:
    if token in window:
        print('^{}^ '.format(token))
    else:
        print('{} '.format(token))
    window.append(token)
    window = window[-30:] #trim to last 30 entries
```

And then pipe your stdout into some file.

Or make a new list:

```
window = []
tokens2 = []
for token in tokens:
    if token in window:
        tokens2.append('^{}^'.format(token))
    else:
        tokens2.append(token)
    window.append(token)
    window = window[-30:] #trim to last 30 entries
print(tokens2)
```

Comment: Okey, looks very promising! I applied your code to the program and this is what I got (Swedish txt-file):

['hejsan']
repeated token hejsan
['hejsan', 'hejsan']
['hejsan', 'hejsan', 'namn']
['hejsan', 'hejsan', 'namn', 'är']
['hejsan', 'hejsan', 'namn', 'är', 'parveln']
['hejsan', 'hejsan', 'namn', 'är', 'parveln', 'och']
repeated token namn
['hejsan', 'hejsan', 'namn', 'är', 'parveln', 'och', 'namn']

My next question is, how do i Mark these words so that for example, the word "hejsan" occurs 2 times, I want to mark the word that occurs more than 1 time within the next 30 words like ^hejsan^

Comment: @user3376110 Why would you want to vandalize this answer?